# SCN to TimeStamp - wrong expression?

Tags: oracle, time, timestamp, oracle12c, systimestamp

I have SCN:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP_TO_SCN(SYSTIMESTAMP) SCN FROM DUAL;
```

I can convert it to time stamp:

```
SELECT SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(6480157) FROM DUAL;
```

When I want to mix this two select Im getting error:

```
SELECT SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(SELECT TIMESTAMP_TO_SCN(SYSTIMESTAMP) FROM DUAL) FROM DUAL;
```

`ORA-00936: missing expression`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use

```
SELECT SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(TIMESTAMP_TO_SCN(SYSTIMESTAMP)) FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 2):

@F.Madsen has the correct and simplest answer, but just to illustrate, you can get to the result following your logic:

```
SELECT SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(SCN) FROM
(
  SELECT (TIMESTAMP_TO_SCN(SYSTIMESTAMP)) SCN FROM DUAL
);
```